# Cannot connect through socket

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I have a problem that's driving me crazy.
Let's say I have client and server (TCP connection):

```
public class ServerTCP {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket srvr = new ServerSocket(4380);
        Socket skt = srvr.accept();
        System.out.print("Client has connected!\n");
        skt.close();
        srvr.close();
    }
}

public class ClientTCP {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        Socket skt = new Socket("myIPaddress", 4380);
    }
}
```

If I replace IP address from ClientTCP with "localhost", everything works fine. When I start ServerTCP, go to http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/, enter 4380 and hit Check, I got message from terminal "Client has connected!". So that should mean that port forwarding is right and I can receive connections. But, when I try to connect from ClientTCP I cannot do it. No matter what I do (disabled ufw, tried different ports), it's just stuck and I eventually I get connection timeout.

I also tried same thing with Netty, same problem occurs. I am using XUbuntu 
16.04 LTS, if that helps. I have no idea what else should I do.

Comment: Did you try connecting with ClientTCP from another computer?

Comment: Yup, didn't work..

Comment: Your host cannot connect *outwards* to its own external IP address. Configuration problem, probably firewall. Off topic.